# Error "Printer 'MFC6890CDW' may not be connected."

Tags: printing

I tried to print the test page, but I got this error message. I installed the LPR driver first, then the cupswrapper from this site: http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-6890CDW

How can I fix this?

The Cups error-log:

```
E [03/Jun/2011:21:05:52 +0200] [CGI] Timeout reached
E [03/Jun/2011:21:05:52 +0200] [CGI] Timeout reached
E [03/Jun/2011:21:11:44 +0200] [Job 2] Keine %%BoundingBox: Kommentar im Header!
E [03/Jun/2011:21:15:52 +0200] [Job 4] Keine %%BoundingBox: Kommentar im Header!
```

- Printer: Brother MFC6890CDW
- OS: Ubuntu 11.04
- URI: usb:/dev/usb/lp0
- The output of `dpkg -l grep -i` brother:

  ```
  ii  brother-cups-wrapper-common     1.0.0-10-0ubuntu5     Common files for Brother cups wrapper packages
  ii  brother-cups-wrapper-extra      1.2.1-0ubuntu3        Cups Wrapper drivers for extra brother printers
  ii  brother-lpr-drivers-common      1.0.0-4-0ubuntu1      Common files for brother-lpr-drivers packages
  ii  brother-lpr-drivers-extra       1.2.0-2-0ubuntu4      rc  mfc6890cdwlpr     1.1.2-4     Brother lpr Inkjet Printer Definitions
  ```

Now I installed the drivers from the software center, but in none of the desciptions the exact name of my printer. It isn't even recognized in the print-dialogue now.

I think the issue is that the printer uses Wifi and I was using Ethernet. Apparently can either be used over LAN or WLAN, but not both at the same time. I will try to access it via WLAN later.

Comment: How are you connecting?

Comment: It's a network printer and I use d-LAN (http://www.tobi-tech.de/images/d-lan.gif), which basically is ethernet.

Comment: Looks like it can't find the printer. Did you open the printer Gui and configure it for a network printer?

Comment: It would help if you  give more information. Mention the printer model and how you connected it physically and OS version you are using.  Also right click the properties of the printer (System -> administration -> printing, select printer, right click it and see properties) and add the Device URI.

Comment: Are you sure you followed all the "pre-required procedures" before install (and the printer was turned on & connected)? I had problems with my DCP145C when i forgot these (and I hardly could uninstall the .deb package due to not meeting the requirements and getting cramped). You could send the output of "dpkg -l | grep -i brother" command...

Comment: Which pre-required procedures? I tried to install the cupswrapper first but it said that I needed to install the LPR driver first. I did so and installed the Cupswrapper. 

The output of dpkg -l  grep -i brother:

rc  brother-lpr-drivers-extra             1.2.0-2-0ubuntu4                           LPR drivers for extra brother printers
ii  mfc6890cdwcupswrapper                 1.1.2-4                                    Brother CUPS Inkjet Printer Definitions
ii  mfc6890cdwlpr                         1.1.2-4                                    Brother lpr Inkjet Printer Definitions

Comment: @Toxicbits When adding new information add it to your question, they get buried in the comments otherwise. Also, did you notice that the Brother drivers are included in ubuntu? There's really no need to go and manually install them.

Comment: Your device URI starts with usb://, that's wrong for a network printer. [In this forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195552) `lpd://<defined_IP>/BINARY_P1` is recommended for an MFC-6490CW (the first letter is a lowercase L).

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution:

1. First, download the lpr driver (deb) from this site: http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-6890CDW
2. Install it and ignore the error message
3. Download the Cupswrapper driver (deb) from the same site
4. Install it and ignore the error message
5. Open the printer management
6. Click on 'Add a new printer'
7. Choose 'Network printer' in the side pane
8. Choose the 'LPD network printer via DNS-SD'

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue with an Epson printer. Have a scanner plugged in by usb which triggered the network printer to not print. Error message was

> Error “Printer 'EPSON-PX-105-Series-8' may not be connected

and something like, "ran out of ink". Which was not true at all.

```
:~$ lpstat -p && lsusb
printer EPSON-PX-105-Series now printing EPSON-PX-105-Series-8.  enabled since Fri 16 Jan 2015 12:14:15 PM JST
Unable to locate printer.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0109 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04a9:190a Canon, Inc. CanoScan LiDE 210
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0483:2016 STMicroelectronics Fingerprint Reader
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:2110 Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2) [Bluetooth Controller]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

As dumb as this sounds, the solution was:

1. kill the power to the printer
2. turn the power on to the printer
3. Push the printer power button (turn it on)

It then printed

In the process learned about

- lpstat -p && lsusb
- http://localhost:631/printers/

Credit goes entirely to:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=929596&page=3